# Task scheduler history - get commands and arguments executed for each task already launched - using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, task, scheduler

Anyone would know if it is possible to get from the history task schedules, the command and arguments executed of all the tasks ?

I have a .ps1 script that obtains from the task scheduler history, three values: data of execution, taskname and result code.

```
$EventFilter = @{
    LogName = 'Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational'
    Id = 201 #action completed
    StartTime = [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-10)
}
# PropertySelector for the Correlation id (the InstanceId) and task name
[string[]]$PropertyQueries = @(
    'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="InstanceId"]'
    'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="TaskName"]'
    'Event/EventData/Data[@Name="ResultCode"]'
)
$PropertySelector = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogPropertySelector @(,$PropertyQueries)

# Loop through the start events
$TaskInvocations = foreach($StartEvent in Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $EventFilter){

    # Grab the InstanceId and Task Name from the start event
    $InstanceId,$TaskName,$ResultCode = $StartEvent.GetPropertyValues($PropertySelector)

    # Create custom object with the name and start event, query end event by InstanceId
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TaskName = $TaskName
        StartTime = $StartEvent.TimeCreated
        ResultCode= $ResultCode
    }
}
$TaskInvocations
```

Now I need to know what was the command and arguments executed in each task...
I don't find anything... :-( I'm beggining to think that this is not possible...

any idea, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What value or properties are you trying to access? `Get-WinEvent` returns lots of information. However, none of them show the commands executed. The closest you could get is the trigger.

Comment: Hi again, I need to access the command and argument executed by a task in the past... data who is located in the Action label, in the textbox: Program/script + Arguments

Comment: Did you know if it is possible? The goal is to save an historic of all tasks executed in a data in the past. With Get-WinEvent i get TaskName, resultCode and StartTime, but no info of command+arguments... :-(.   Thanks in advance!!

Comment: none of them show the commands executed. The closest you could get is the trigger.